# Upgrade Netbeans without losing the configuration of last version

Tags: netbeans, upgrade, netbeans-7

I'm working with `netbeans 7.4`. I have created many macros and custom many shortcuts. Now I want to download the new `netbeans` version `8.0`. How can I use the last configuration( `macros`, `shortcuts`, and `plugins` list, etc.) ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just point the new version to the old userdir: http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansUserFAQ#Configuration  (or copy the old one to a new directory and point 8.0 to the copy)

Comment: As it says in the [installation instructions of the RC](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/install.html#upgrading), if there is an older version of Netbeans installed, you get asked if you want to import settings and plugins from the old version.